# Java writing map key to file for the number of times it is found in the input file (stored as the value of the map)

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, key, treemap

I have a text file that contains thousands of lines of 1 word/character. I have created a `TreeMap<String, Integer> s = new TreeMap<>();` that stores each line from the text file as the key, and the value of the map is an integer that counts how many times the same word was found in the file (Duplicates).

I want to now write the results to the output file w, where the duplicates are printed as many times as they appear (counted as the map value).

As of now, I have the following code to write to the output file:

```
for (String value : s.keySet()) {
    w.println(value);
}
```

This however only writes each key once in the output file. Essentially what I am trying to get is:

map:

```
[(hello, 1); (apple, 3); (java, 2); (python, 1)]
```

The output file should be:

```
apple
apple
apple
hello
java
java
python
```

Comment: And... what have you tried? What's the difficulty you're facing? You seem to know how maps work, and you seem to know how to loop, so you have everything you need.

Comment: it writes it once, because `s.keySet()` returns a set of keys, that means => you got all the words, but not, how offten they appear. What you have to do is a second loop inside the first one `for(int i =0; i < s.get(value); i++)` and put your `w.println(value);` inside this inner loop

Comment: I have tried a few different things, mainly trying to write a for loop that writes the key to the output file a specific number of times based on the value that corresponds to that key. For some reason however, when I add the for loop and try to run the program, it doesn't write to the output file anymore. I am trying to figure out why this is happening, and figure out some different ways I can implement this.

Comment: Then post that code you tried, so we can help you find the problem it has.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the entries of the map, not just the keys. The entry captures the key (which hold the word to write) and the value (which hold the number of times it should be written).

To get a hold of the entries, you call [`Map.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--). This returns a `Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` in your case. [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) represents an entry of the map. Then:

- [`getKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey--) returns the key of this entry, which is the word to write.
- [`getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue--) returns the value of this entry, which is the number of times it should be written.

Sample code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : s.entrySet()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
        w.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to use the keySet() method to retrieve the words is correct.  Remember, you also have a corresponding value for each key which indicates how many times each word has been repeated.Make sure you use the value for each key so that you can print each word/character "value" number of times.